# Invoking external types that call files via relative path

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm working on a project that provides third party developers with an API containing template classes they can inherit from. This developer must inform the main process that they've created a type that inherits from one of those templates. To do this, the developer calls a function:

```
internal Dictionary<string, Type> Templates = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

public void RegisterTemplate(string ID, Type template)
{
    ...
    Templates.Add(ID, template);
    ...
}
```

Note: RegisterTemplate is a member of the program, not of an external library.

**Functions in the type a developer provides in to this function call relative paths such as "Audio/somefile.wav" or "Models/somefile.vox".** The third party developer compiles their inheriting classes into a DLL and places it in a folder separate from the program in order to be imported later by the program.

If the program calls the functions described in bold above, will the path associated be relative to the program that invokes the Type, or relative to the DLL that the invoked Type originates from?

---

**To Clarify:** rather than the relative paths of the executing assembly or DLL, I'm talking in regards to the paths called within the DLL, like so:

```
File.Open("Audio/somefile.wav");
```

If this code is called from a function within the DLL, and the type that contains this code is invoked by code in my executable, will this path be relative to the executable that invoked the Type, or the DLL that contains the invoked Type?

Comment: Are the dlls also written in C#?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg All of my code is in C#. The third party code can be any .NET language of their choice, provided that it gets compiled into a managed library like C#.

Comment: @TristenHorton it's not relative to any of them. It's relative to **application current directory** (check Environment.CurrentDirectory) and it's not tied to executing or entry assembly location (but it **may** be related to entry assembly location, just don't rely on this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Fruchtzwerg and Adriano Repetti for their input;

**The directory that the relative path is relative to is dependent upon the Environment, not the executable or DLL called it.** In this case, the Environment's CurrentDirectory is the directory that the Executable is contained in.

The file opened in this case would be located at "C:/.../ApplicationDirectory/Sounds/somefile.wav"

Answer (score 0):

The path depends on the way you call them.

For example

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

returns the path of your executable (also if calling from your dll),

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

would return the path of your dll.

Look at this [discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4d2e5f29-e503-4483-924c-c39aae35fcf6/get-path-of-executing-dll?forum=csharplanguage) or this [post](http://headrevision.com/2011/04/05/c-path-of-dll-vs-application-path/) for more information and examples.

Depending on MSDN the File.Open()-Methode is calling the [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So you are calling files relative to your executable.

Comment: I added some clarification to my question; I'm asking in regards to reading/writing a file, and whether the path associated will be relative to the DLL containing the invoked Type, or to the executable that's invoking the Type.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my answer. Hope I understood it right.